# Delay when removing row in postgres with knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a local postgres database running on my machine. I use node.js to access it. I have a table called 'friends' where every row is a user and a friend. I also have a table called 'users' where every row has all basic info about a user(e.g name and such).

When I want to remove a friendship between two users I have to remove two rows from the 'friends' table. I do this with this function:

```
const removeFriend = async (clientId, friendId) => {
  // initiate transaction
  return db
    .transaction((trx) => {
      // remove friendship from client
      trx('friends')
        .where({ user_id: clientId, friend_id: friendId })
        .del()
        .then(() => {
          // remove friendship from friend
          return trx('friends').where({ user_id: friendId, friend_id: clientId }).del();
        })
        // if all good then commit
        .then(trx.commit)
        //  if bad then rollback
        .catch(trx.rollback);
    })
    .catch(() => 'error');
};
```

I call the removeFriend function this way `removeFriend(clientId, friendId)`

Then when i want to get a list of all friends with their names from the database i use this function:

```
const getUserFriends = async (clientId) => {
  // get friends
  return db('friends')
    .where({ user_id: clientId })
    .join('users', 'users.id', 'friends.friend_id')
    .select('friends.friend_id', 'users.name')
    .then((friends) => friends)
    .catch(() => 'error');
};
```

I call the getUserFriends function this way `await getUserFriends(clientId)`

The problem is that when I use removeFriend function and then directly use the getUserFriends function i get a list where the users are still friends. However, If i look in the database the rows have been deleted so naturaly i should get a list where the users are not friends. Do I use the await wrong or something?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet where you call both of these functions? You might have forgotten `await` before `removeFriend` call.

Comment: Also, `return trx('friends')` in your transaction body. I'm almost certain the this is the issue.

Comment: I removed return as you said and added a await when i call removeFriend function and noq it works. Thanks